# How can I block third-party scripts on Selenium tests?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, integration-testing, browsermob

My Selenium tests are being slowed by third-party scripts that are not necessary to the tests.

How can I block them? Preferably I'd like to block requests to everywhere but *localhost*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solutions offered elsewhere online are:**

- Block unwanted domains (e.g., *.facebook.com) by editing your hostfiles.
- Route all your tests through [BrowserMob](https://bmp.lightbody.net) which can be configured to filter requests.

Both options seemed like overkill to me. Editing the host files affects your whole system, and using BrowserMob introduces new [problems](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy/issues).

**Here's another way:** Use a PAC file to configure the browser to connect to localhost directly, and attempt to connect to everything else through an unavailable proxy.

Selenium code (Java):

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
proxy.setProxyType(Proxy.ProxyType.PAC);
proxy.setProxyAutoconfigUrl("http://localhost:8080/my-pac-file.pac");
capabilities.setCapability("proxy", proxy);
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(INSTANCE, capabilities);
```

The PAC file:

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {
    if (host.toLowerCase() === "localhost"){
      return "DIRECT"; // whitelisted
    }
  return "PROXY 127.0.0.1:9876"; // blocked (bad proxy)
}
```

Comment: Is there a specific folder the PAC file should be located in? Does this location vary with different browsers?

Comment: @Grasshopper Anywhere that it can be retrieved with a HTTP request.

Comment: Note (at least with the Chrome driver) you can use [data URIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) so that you don't have to host an actual file anywhere, but that `FindProxyForURL` function can be stored in a string variable in code

Comment: Indeed, something like this works! https://crbug.com/839566#c8

Comment: Pro-tip: Chrome recently removed the ability to declare PAC files with a file URL ('file:///') so the pac file must be accessible via a http request (hosted somewhere)